# ReGex - Python - From word till the first dot in a sentencce

Tags: regex, python-2.7, sentence

```
text = "hello there. I would like to capture from this point till the end"
capture= re.findall(r'(point).$',text)
print (capture)
```

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `.*`? There isn't precisely one character between `point` and the end of the string.

Comment: oh no no ~ I mean I wanna capture from the word point till the end of the sentence:

"...point till the end"

Comment: Yes, and unless that's precisely one character `.$` cannot match.

Comment: oh yeah but it does not include "point" word though. So can I actually include that too with this code?

Comment: oh sorry I got it ~ yeah! Many thanks... simple as hell..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to capture everything after a certain word till the next dot or the end of the string:

```
point(.*?)(?:\.|$)
```

Here, the `(.*?)` is a capturing group matching any characters 0 or more number of times in a [non-greedy fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). `(?:\.|$)` is a non-capturing group matching either a dot or an end of the string.

Demo:

```
>>> re.findall(r'point(.*?)(?:\.|$)', "hello there. I would like to capture from this point till the end")
[' till the end']
>>> re.findall(r'point(.*?)(?:\.|$)', "hello there. I would like to capture from this point till the end of the sentence. And now there is something else here.")
[' till the end of the sentence']
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe this works perfectly!

Comment: much of appreciation! It provided me many solutions! Even after some time, this is really useful script you have provided!